How to remove a query from a MySQL master/slave setup that is causing the slave instance of MySQL to crash?
Specifically I have a query that is trying to grant privileges that for whatever reason is causing the slave MySQL instance to crash. As a result I can't even bring up the mysql console from the command line. It is running in Linux.
Is there a way for me to manually remove the query command from the replication list of commands so that it can continue processing? And if so how?
Here is a sample from the logs:
2024-05-01T01:10:38.045326Z 5 [Warning] [MY-010590] [Repl] An unexpected event sequence was detected by the IO thread while queuing the event received from source 'mysql-bin.000402' binary log file, at position 15012066.
2024-05-01T01:10:38Z UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;

which then goes on to display the GRANT_ALL_PRIVILEGES command.
And if nothing can I just delete that one mysql-bin file? I know it won't be completely replicated but I need to get past this issue.
